# Share a USB sound card over a network/bluetooth (Mac & PC)

Tags: windows, mac, wireless-networking, audio, sound-card

I've been wondering how I can stream audio to an external Edirol USB sound card, wirelessly, on both Mac and PC.

I'm not looking for high quality transmission, just to play mp3s from my Mac laptop to a USB sound card that is attached to two very nice balanced studio reference monitors.

Is there any way I can firstly power the sound card box, and secondly, provide with an audio stream along it's USB input.

I've looked at the Belkin USB hub, and I have a Time Capsule with the AirPort interface inside. These things seem to do vaguely what I want but when it comes to audio, the specifications are less clear.

Any suggestions very welcome.

Comment: it sounds like what you're wanting is a media extender. what you are actually asking i do not think is possible. most likely your USB sound device requires some sort of drivers on a host computer to operate, so running it just off a USB hub would probably not work.

Comment: That's a good point! Perhaps if the sound card was attached to a PC, then the laptop can then send it's audio to the PC over a network... I've seen software for this. Apple have "AirPort enabled" speakers but they're not my speakers! :)